# Winform equivalent to Android's fragments?

Tags: winforms, android-fragments

You know, like in CCleaner app where main activity is on the left side of the app and the right side area is changeable fragment.
http://cache.filehippo.com/img/ex/3049__ccleaner1.png

How to do it? I imagine I could do it by putting all fragments in the same place and just change their visibility to show just 1 at the moment, but that would make the code a whole lot of mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in the past by using UserControls. It's worked nicely for things like choosing payment methods (cash, cc, cheque...).

There are a couple of options for changing the display, either have all the UserControls present on the form and hide or show them as required or have an empty placeholder panel and use a factory to construct the appropriate UserControl as needed. I've done both and it really depends on the complexity (and expected longevity and users) of the project as to which is appropriate.

Using a Model-View-Presenter pattern helped with managing all of this.

What you don't want to end up with is a massive switch statement that changes the visibility of dozens of manually positioned controls individually. I've seen it and that way lies madness.

Comment: That UserControl rings the bell. But without switch statement to change the visibility of many UserControl, what better idea are you suggesting?

Comment: What I meant was, avoid a big switch statement that changes the visibility of individual labels and textboxes. In projects with an MVP structure I've used factories that query model objects to determine what UI to display.